# Splitting data from text file

Tags: python

My program is reading from a text file line by line. I want it to split each line's numbers into separate variables. For example:

This is the string it reads from the line in the text file:

```
FTSE,D,20160104,6242.32,6242.32,6071.01,6093.43,0
```

I would like each value before the comma placed into a variable:

```
A = 'FTSE'

B = 'D'

C = '20160104'

...
```

Pseudo code:

```
for line in file:
     line.split(',') 
     A = firstsplit 
     B = secondsplit
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for line in file:
     A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H = line.split(',')
```

This only works if you are sure that the line will only contain 8 parts.